# How to get custom label for GCP resources like VM instances while calling the Time series API

Tags: google-cloud-platform, command-line-interface, gcloud

I have created a VM instance in the GCP and added some **custom labels** for that VM instance.
I want to retrieve the monitoring data of that VM using a java program.
I am able to get the monitoring data of that VM by calling the **timeSeries** API but the response of time **timeSeries** API does not include My Custom Labels.
Is there any way to get custom labels as a part of the **timeSeries** response?

Comment: I have added an answer that solves the retrieval of the custom labels, but I still encourage you to provide more information on what you are currently using and what you are getting so we have even more context of your scenario.

Answer (score 2):

I did not find a method to do it using the timeSeries resource from the Monitoring API itself, but if you know the `project_id`, `zone` and `intance_id` you could simply use the [`instances.get`](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances/get) method from the Compute API.